# Find specific string and output the whole line Python

Tags: python

I am having the following input txt file:

```
17,21.01.2019,0,0,0,0,E,75,meter tamper alarm
132,22.01.2019,64,296,225,996,A,,
150,23.01.2019,63,353,351,805,A,,
213,24.01.2019,64,245,244,970,A,,
201,25.01.2019,86,297,364,943,A,,
56,26.01.2019,73,678,678,1437,A,,
201,27.01.2019,83,654,517,1212,A,,
117,28.01.2019,58,390,202,816,A,,
69,29.01.2019,89,354,282,961,C,,
123,30.01.2019,53,267,206,852,A,,
```

Need to make a python program that can parse through the file.
I need to find all the lines not containing A or C and output those lines in a new file. 
I'm completely stuck after trying several regex :( can you help me ?

Comment: Read the file line by line, split it by commas and check if any of the elements is A or C.

Comment: Can't you just use `if "string" in lineString:` and check if it does not contain both "A" and "C"

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'A' not in line or 'C' not in line:
            print(line)
```

OR Better, as your file content seems to resemble a csv(Comma Seperated Values) format, use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) for better manipulations

**Read the file**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename', header=None, sep=',')

     0           1   2    3    4     5  6     7                   8
0   17  21.01.2019   0    0    0     0  E  75.0  meter tamper alarm
1  132  22.01.2019  64  296  225   996  A   NaN                 NaN
2  150  23.01.2019  63  353  351   805  A   NaN                 NaN
3  213  24.01.2019  64  245  244   970  A   NaN                 NaN
4  201  25.01.2019  86  297  364   943  A   NaN                 NaN
5   56  26.01.2019  73  678  678  1437  A   NaN                 NaN
6  201  27.01.2019  83  654  517  1212  A   NaN                 NaN
7  117  28.01.2019  58  390  202   816  A   NaN                 NaN
8   69  29.01.2019  89  354  282   961  C   NaN                 NaN
9  123  30.01.2019  53  267  206   852  A   NaN                 NaN
```

**Output**

```
print(df[~df[6].str.contains('A|C', regex=True)])

    0           1  2  3  4  5  6     7                   8
0  17  21.01.2019  0  0  0  0  E  75.0  meter tamper alarm
```

Comment: Updated. Please check @Guy

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with open(r'file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'A' not in line or 'C' not in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: You are simply great, thank you for those fast responses! 
Another small question is there a way also to exclude any negative numbers?

Comment: @SakrayaamiS not as simple as it is right now. like this you are only comparing strings. you could search for `'-' not in line`. but for the I would recommend to use pandas like @Vishnudev did

Comment: you could split at every `,` and try to cast it to float and check if its negative